# Replace string with another string in vi editor

Tags: vim, vi

I have a `template.php` file where I want to change every occurence of `apple` with `grape` throughout the file. At the moment,I am having to painstakingly edit the entire file to find where to change. Sometimes the name is like this in the file, `apple_button` and sometimes it is just `apple`.

I am using `vi` to edit.

Comment: That's very basic vi / Vim functionality, covered by most tutorials on the web. Also, learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: Thanks, yes I couldn't actually live without it. Unless I stopped doing computer stuff :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file `template.php` using vi editor. After opening it, press escape button and type below.

```
:%s/apple/grape/g
```

Comment: Brilliant :! so this is just a vi editor command?

Comment: It is just the vi editor that you use in Linux environments.

Comment: Glad that I could help you again :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/apple/grape/g' template.php
```

If you use `vi`, you can do in `command mode`:

```
:%s/apple/grape/g
```

Answer (score 1):

try use the command sed to change.

```
sed -e 's/apple/grape/g'  filethatyouwantchange
```

this will just show the output , if you want to change the file use the parameter -i:

```
sed -i -e 's/apple/grape/g'  filethatyouwantchange
```

if you are using `vi` or `vim` you can do the same thing with the file open

```
:%s/apple/grape/g
```

Comment: thanks but Ramesh beat everyone to it.